# Manupulate a dataframe to create a pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe (around 100K rows). Structure is like this -

```
df={'time':[1,1,1],'counter':['A','B','C'],'ID':[0,0,0],'value':[1,1,3]}
In [11]: pd.DataFrame(df)
Out[11]: 
   ID counter  time  value
0   0       A     1      1
1   0       B     1      1
2   0       C     1      3
```

I want to create a pivot that uses Column = Counter as the column names. So something like -

```
    ID time A B C 
  0 0  1    1 1 3
```

How can I do this in an fast and efficient way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table:`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
new_df=df.pivot_table(columns='counter',index=['ID','time'],values='value').reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
print(new_df)
```

---

```
   ID  time  A  B  C
0   0     1  1  1  3
```